# How can i add the android emulator inside the eclipse ide?

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, motodev-studio

See the below screenshot, on right hand side emulator is loaded inside the eclipse window

Motorola Developer Studio have this option

[image: Emulator Linked with eclipse]

IS that possible to add my android default emulator any other emulator to the eclipse

Please provide the steps

Comment: yes @andygoestohollywood, there is a tool like the above screenshot

Tool: Motodev Tool

that is also made using the eclipse

If don't know about eclipse please don't comment

Comment: so what's the question then?